# start downloading of a generated file and then interrupt download

Tags: php

Does anyone know how i php could generate and random file and start downloading for few second, after what just interrupt download? I need to test some upload/download scripts and need some really large files generated, but to be interrupted on half way of download. I was going to integrate the test utility with my debug script.

this can start download of file, but how i can interrupt download after random amount of time?

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
echo $content;
exit();
```

Comment: Just disconnect client or server from internet ?

Comment: Good idea) TQ. But any script may do same job for user session?)

Comment: this was joke Harikrishnan, i asked about php) but wall, i found answer by my self thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this bash script and save it as `interrupter.sh`. Run it in background by `./interrupter.sh &`

```
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
    /etc/init.d/networking stop
    sleep 3
   /etc/init.d/networking start
   sleep 10
done
```

It will interrupt download for 3 seconds. You may customize it by changing param to sleep.

Comment: Thanks harrikrishnan best answer!